# while installing webdriverio node unable to find dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, webdriver-io

While installing the module `webdriverio` using `npm`, I am getting the following error:

```
sudo npm install webdriverio
[sudo] password for username: 
npm WARN package.json indexof@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriverio
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriverio
npm WARN engine webdriverio@5.4.9: wanted: {"node":">= 4.8.5"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.15","npm":"1.3.5"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grapheme-splitter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/css-value
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.merge
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rgb2hex
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serialize-error
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wdio/logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wdio/config
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wdio/repl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css-value
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: css-value@'^0.0.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "webdriverio"
npm ERR! cwd /home/username/research
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.merge
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serialize-error
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.zip
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grapheme-splitter
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rgb2hex
npm http 405 https://registry.npmjs.org/wdio/repl
npm ERR! TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR!     at Function.keys (native)
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:708:24)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "webdriverio"
npm ERR! cwd /home/username/research
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! type called_on_non_object
npm http 405 https://registry.npmjs.org/wdio/logger
npm ERR! TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR!     at Function.keys (native)
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:708:24)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "webdriverio"
npm ERR! cwd /home/username/research
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! type called_on_non_object
npm http 405 https://registry.npmjs.org/wdio/config
npm ERR! TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR!     at Function.keys (native)
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:708:24)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "webdriverio"
npm ERR! cwd /home/username/research
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! type called_on_non_object
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/username/research/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Could someone please help with this? I do not understand why this is happening since when I do `npm info loadash.merge`, the module version is clearly present. I have also tried to see what my `$NODE_PATH` contains (as some answers on `stackoverflow` suggest), and it seems to be pointing towards the correct path of `node`, or at least the path where `nvm` installed `node`:

`/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/node`

Additionally, I am not sure about this particular warning:
`npm WARN engine webdriverio@5.4.9: wanted: {"node":">= 4.8.5"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.15","npm":"1.3.5"})` My node version is `10.15.1` and not `0.10.15`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the css-value library based on this part of the stack trace:

> npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: css-value@'^0.0.1'

Try to resolve this by doing:  `npm i css-value`

Additionally, your stack trace is complaining about using an outdated version of Node. I would consider updating node since your version is very old:

> npm WARN engine webdriverio@5.4.9: wanted: {"node":">= 4.8.5"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.15","npm":"1.3.5"})

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to do `npm i css-value` but it gives a huge series of other dependencies. Also when I do `node -v` it gives me `v10.15.1` which is supposed to be one of the newer versions, I am not sure why its reading it as a different version.

Comment: Did those dependencies install correctly? Maybe you have your path variable set to another version of node?

Comment: Not sure. There is a warning about `unmet dependency` and then these errors: `npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15`
`npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5`
`npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID`
`npm ERR!`

Comment: I've added the path by doing this: `echo PATH="$PATH:`which node`"` but its still giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably with using `sudo` in the npm install. You can check this out by using `sudo node -v` and it will probably give you a different node version than your nvm installed one, this would indicate that node in your server is broken in some places due some previous installation. To circumvent it I suggest the following that has worked for me for similar issues.

```
sudo su
nvm alias default 10.15.1
npm cache clean --force
npm install webdriverio
```

If it still gives syntax errors due to dependencies, use

```
npm install webdriverio --unsafe-perm
```